# How do you transform a txt file to CSV file?

Tags: python

I just spent an hour trying to find the following error: I read a txt file with a CSV reader which was successful. What I didn't realize was that every row was a single string. I want the entries of my CSV file to be the entities that are split by space. Is there a simple way to make this transformation?

Comment: Please add some sample data from the txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the `delimiter` option to set what character to use between the entries.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```